# Flutter: Get the position of all the letters. (Game)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a game, but I can't change the letter that matches more than once.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I hope someone can help me, thanks.

I leave a demonstration video, the result of the word is DOMINGO

The problem I perceive is that when I press the key or it is assigned only at the beginning.

When it must be completed with all possible matches.

[YouTube Video Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOP-ehmr-V0)

**This is my dart function.**

```
  String word = 'domingo';
  String key = 'o'; // OnTap button "O"
  List<Word> positionsFound = List<Word>();

  _word(){
    String wordEmpty = '';
    for(int i=0; i<word.length; i++){
      if(key.isEmpty){
        wordEmpty = wordEmpty+'_';
      } else {
        wordEmpty = wordEmpty+'_';
        int position = word.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase());
        if(position == i){
          positionsFound.add(Word(key, position));
          print(position); // The position must be 1 and 6, it only gives me 1.

        }
      }
    }


    for(int i=0; i<positionsFound.length; i++){
      wordEmpty = wordEmpty.replaceFirst('_', positionsFound[i].key, positionsFound[i].position);
    }

    return wordEmpty;
  }


class Word {
    String key;
    int position;

    Word(this.key, this.position);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I realized that indexof allows you to start from the last search you performed.

```
if(key.isNotEmpty){
          int position = word.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase());
          while(position != -1){
            if(position != -1){
              positionsFound.add(Word(key, position));
            }
            position = word.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase(), position+1);
          }
        }
```